# Compiling openssl 1.0.0e, "openssl version" still returns 0.9.8k.. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, openssl

I am trying to install openssl 1.0.0e on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS
I tried using some procedures one of which was

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl  
sudo make
sudo make install
```

After this it installs without errors but when i do `openssl version` it still tells me `OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do `which openssl`. most likely its going to be `/usr/bin/openssl` which is the system copy and not the copy you installed and with a prefix of `/usr/local/openssl` the binary is going to end up at `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `which openssl` to find out which copy you are running - I suspect it's the default, older one.

You'll need to set `PATH` to contain `/usr/local/openssl/bin` to get the new one:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/openssl/bin:$PATH
```