# OSX's openssl version is diffrent from brew's openssl

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

I just typed *openssl version* in terminal and I got following result:

OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

So I ran **brew update** and **brew upgrade openssl**.

Which the first one returned *Updated Homebrew from 7afeb3af to 8cabfe85.*, And second one returned *openssl-1.0.1g already installed*.
So typed *brew link --force openssl*.

After above procedure I typed *openssl version* And I got the same result

OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013.

How can I update openssl on mac osx 10.9.3?

Comment: if it says you have 1.0.1g installed, then you probably do, as well as 0.9.8y. try `whereis openssl` to see where both versions are living. most likely the 0.9.8 version exists earlier in your path than 1.0.1 But regardless, offtopic, not a programming question. Try superuser or serverfault for systems configuration issues.

Comment: Openssl is in"/usr/bin/openssl" and brew is "/usr/local/bin/brew" by which command

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling openssl 1.0.0e, "openssl version" still returns 0.9.8k.. What am i doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654502/compiling-openssl-1-0-0e-openssl-version-still-returns-0-9-8k-what-am-i-doi)

Answer (score 5):

Run `brew info openssl` and follow the instructions there. Do not try to `--force` link the latest openssl with the one that comes installed with OSX by default. (0.9.8)

Specifically it'll ask you to add the Homebrew version of openssl (should be 1.0.2 as of this date) into your $PATH.
`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Note: Make sure to remove any `export PATH` lines from the bash_profile, since this line above exports it for you appending the rest of the $PATH variable to the end. To view the bash profile use `vi ~/.bash_profile`

Doing this should fix any problems with installing packages (especially Ruby Gems that need compiling).

Answer (score 4):

So here's what is going on. You have two copies of OpenSSL.

1. Version 0.9.8 - located at `/usr/bin/openssl`, pre-installed on OS X
2. Version 1.0.1g - located at `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/bin/openssl`, installed by brew.

When you ran `brew upgrade openssl`, you actually ran `brew install openssl` since brew had not yet install openssl on your system. (Remember, brew doesn't control all the software on your computer - only what it installed).

Turns out that the message of `brew install openssl`:

```
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

The OpenSSL provided by OS X is too old for some software.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

This actually explains that OS X comes preinstalled. Using a different non-system openssl may cause issues if you change from the default openssl. Hence, brew kindly did not link it into your /usr/local which is probably part of your path.

I presume you wanted to upgrade the openssl on you box because some package you were trying to install required a newer version. Ahoy - the message tells you that you should install that software package and point it at your new shiny brew openssl.

Comment: How do I point it to the new version of openssl instead of 0.9.8?